# error - MooTools is not defined

Tags: mootools, joomla2.5, mootools-more

Joomla 2.5 website:

212.113.141.98/~artstorm/

Getting error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: 
MooTools is not defined - mootools-more.js:13
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'addEvent' - 212.113.141.98/~artstorm/:45
```

Even though mootools-more.js is defined in the source.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have some scripts loading twice, incl. jQuery... I can't find Mootools, were do you load Mootools?

Comment: mootools-more.js is there now, still same issue

Comment: I see you have Mootools Core now. Good. You still have a error there because your `function keepAlive()` is run before the mootools script. Move the script load more up in the code and after the mootools.js file you can add your functions. Let me know if that worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You embed several jquery libraries, it's not recommended and not necessary. 
It looks like you disable mootools in joomla (with a plugin or in your php code) and add it manually in your code. You may remove this lines, enable mootools again, disable all embeds of jquery libraries from plug-ins, and just use the last version. 
If you need old function from jquery (for example "live" method wich is deprecated now) you can use the jquery migrate plugin.
then the scripts embedded in your header should look like this :

```
 <script src="your_url/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="your_url/media/system/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="your_url/media/system/js/caption.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="your_url/media/system/js/mootools-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="your_url/media/system/js/modal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  ...

  <script src="your_url/libraries/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="your_url/libraries/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
  jQuery.noConflict();
  </script>
```